# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. Intentado hacer un organizador de archivos

Tags: datetime, python-3.7, iteradores

Estoy intentando hacer un organizador de archivos por fechas pero no logro hacer que funcione correctamente. No selecciona los archivos individualmente, selecciona la carpeta donde están alojados.
Soy un principiante aún, creo que se nota.

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


main = r'C:\Users\Marcos\Desktop\U'
dest1 = r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\UNUEVO\2018 - 1'
dest2 = r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\UNUEVO\2018 - 2'
dest3 = r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\UNUEVO\2019 - 1'
dest4 = r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\UNUEVO\2019 - 2'
dest5 = r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\UNUEVO\2020 - 1'


date1 = datetime.strptime('2018-1-1', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date2 = datetime.strptime('2018-6-30', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date3 = datetime.strptime('2018-7-1', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date4 = datetime.strptime('2018-12-30', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date5 = datetime.strptime('2019-1-1', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date6 = datetime.strptime('2019-6-30', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date7 = datetime.strptime('2019-7-1', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date8 = datetime.strptime('2019-12-30', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date9 = datetime.strptime('2020-1-1', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
date10 = datetime.strptime('2020-6-30', '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()


for w in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\U'):
    creationdate = (os.path.getmtime(w))
    if date1 <= creationdate <= date2:
        shutil.move(main, dest1)
    elif date3 <= creationdate <= date4:
        shutil.move(main, dest2)
    elif date5 <= creationdate <= date6:
        shutil.move(main, dest3)
    elif date7 <= creationdate <= date8:
        shutil.move(main, dest4)
    elif date9 <= creationdate <= date10:
        shutil.move(main, dest5)
```

Comment: En que linea te da error?

Comment: Otra cosa, que es `main`?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es “os.listdir(...)”? Usa La función type()

Comment: @EdherCarbajal `os.listdir()` retorna una lista, `craeationdate` es de tipo float. El error debe de estar en una parte de la estructura condicional. ://

Comment: @gcoronel99 Antes que nada, gracias por responder :). Efectivamente lo que está mal es el for loop. main es la carpeta de origen (ya lo edité).

Comment: Entonces... Tu problema ya se solucionó?

Comment: main es un directorio. Estas moviendo el directorio main, no el archivo w.

Answer (score 0):

Revise tu código.

Primero que nada, cuando tengas problemas, inserta `print()` en los lugares apropiados para ir viendo que está pasando. Asi habrías resuelto el problema en minutos.

He aqui la versión que use para descubrir el error (tengo Linux, los paths son un poco distintos):

```
main = r'/home/candid/inter'

for w in os.listdir(main):
    print("Archivo w=", w)
```

lo que produce

```
Archivo w= trim.sh~
Archivo w= Dark-Aurora-master
Archivo w= amaya.jpg
```

Como ves, `os.listdir(main)` te devuelve sólo el nombre del archivo, sin el `path`.

A continuación tú escribes:

```
   if date1 <= creationdate <= date2:
        shutil.move(main, dest1)
```

Ahi lo que haces es mover `main`, que es un directorio, no un archivo. Eso explica tu problema.

Ahora, reemplazar `main` por `w` no arregla las cosas:

```
   if date1 <= creationdate <= date2:
        shutil.move(w, dest1)
```

porque `w` es sólo el nombre, y la función `move` necesita el path completo.

¿Cómo obtienes el path completo? Juntando el direcorio `main` con el nombre del archivo `w`, asi:

```
full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(main, w))
```

Entonces, para que la cosa funcione, tienes que escribir:

```
for w in os.listdir(main):
    print("Archivo w=", w)
    full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(main, w))
    print("Archivo Full path=", full_path)
    creationdate = (os.path.getmtime(full_path))
    if date1 <= creationdate <= date2:
        shutil.move(full_path, dest1)
```

Con eso ya puedes arreglar tu programa.